Sudo password unable to enter
unable to enter password in terminal. trying to enter stall commands, ask for  password but will not allow me to enter the password. I am new to linux and assume that the password is my log in for ubantu.

If the terminal asked you to enter your password, enter it.  You will not receive any indication that the password is being accepted until you finish and hit enter.

Welcome to AskUbuntu! If the answers in the linked duplicate don't answer your question, please let us know and we can retract the close votes or reopen your question. Also, please be sure to begin your reply with one of our usernames, like @mchid for example, so that one of us will get a notification for your reply.
